# How do I reverse the contents of one file and put into another in C?

Tags: c, reverse

I'm a novice programmer and was wondering how I can adjust my code make the text that's being placed in file 3, be reversed, as it currently doesn't do that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
printf("\n Enter your desired name of the output file: ");
scanf("%s", filename3);

//opening files for reading and appending 
filepointer1 = fopen(filename1, "r");
filepointer2 = fopen(filename2, "r");
filepointer3 = fopen(filename3, "a");

//intiate counter to move position in files forward
int count = 0;
while (1) {
    //read file one
    if (fgets(linecontents, sizeof linecontents, filepointer1) != NULL) {
        //move pointer up
        count++;
        //paste the current line of file 1 to the end of file 3.
        fprintf(filepointer3, linecontents);
    } else {
        break;
    }
    //read file two
    if (fgets(linecontents, sizeof linecontents, filepointer2) != NULL) {
        //move the pointer up
        count++;

        //paste current line of file 2 to the end of file 3.
        fprintf(filepointer3, linecontents);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

//close all open files
fclose(filepointer1);
fclose(filepointer2);
fclose(filepointer3);
```

Comment: If the file size is reasonable (less than 100MB), then you just read the whole file into memory, and write it out reversed.

Comment: @user3386109 yeah, I'm not sure how you do that lmao

Comment: One advice `fprintf(filepointer3, linecontents);` --> `fprintf(filepointer3, "%s", linecontents);` or Use `fputs`.

Comment: Find the file size, allocate memory, use `fread` then reverse the buffer and use `fwrite`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For the future, you might want to take a look at [ask] for tips on how to get the most out of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

How to save the position of the text in the linked list and reverse it.
sample code(error handling omitted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    long pos;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *add(Node *list, long pos);

int main(void){
    char buff[1024];
    Node *list = NULL;
    long pos;
    FILE *fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while(1){
        long pos = ftell(fin);
        if(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin) == NULL)
            break;
        list = add(list, pos);
    }

    FILE *fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    while(list != NULL){
        pos = list->pos;
        fseek(fin, pos, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin);
        buff[strcspn(buff, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline
        fprintf(fout, "%s\n", buff);
        Node *temp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    fclose(fin);fclose(fout);
}

Node *add(Node *list, long pos){
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->pos = pos;
    node->next = list;
    return node;
}
```